# Are site promotion questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm a moderator on a site, and we have a specific (albeit common) demographic that's sorely lacking, and we'd like to attract that demographic to our user-base, obviously in a tasteful and nondiscriminatory way.

Would it be on-topic for me to ask a question like one of these? I would, of course, tell more details about the type of site, the demographic, and our reasoning, but generally speaking, is there anything specifically wrong with these?

> 1. We're looking to attract *[demographic]* to my *[site]*, how can I build that portion of my user-base?
> 2. I've thought about doing this *[site promotion technique]* with *[this goal in mind]*, might that be a good idea?
> 3. I've thought about doing this *[site promotion technique]* with *[this goal in mind]*, is there history of something like that working?

I'm thinking that the answer to the second one would virtually always be "try it and find out!" so I'm assuming not on that one, not to mention it seems pretty opinion-based at best, but I'm less sure on the other ones.

I feel like the first one is also very opinion-based, but perhaps that falls on the side of ["good subjective?"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Then the third one is just an attempt at making the second one seem more on-topic, so feel free to do with that what you will.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Scope:

That type of question is indeed on topic here. (We even have a related [promotion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotion) tag.)

From the [Tour Page](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Ask about:**
>
> - Creating, expanding, and cultivating communities, their content, and the relationships among members

#### Opinion based or not?

We have almost *all* "good subjective questions." A lot of building a community is based on experience.

Side note, the help center even touches on this "good subjective" type of question:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

Anyway, questions one and three would totally fit, but question two is in a gray area. If you *do* ask that question, make sure to fill it with enough information that it's still possible to get answers based on experience in similar situations.

I might suggest asking the first question and adding *"I've been thinking of doing XYZ, would this work?* to the body instead of asking the second one.